# Infinite groups that admit a discrete, co-compact, bilipschitz action on $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, group-actions

Apart from the abstract types of the crystallographic groups, are there any other abstract groups that admit a proper, co-compact, uniformly bilipschitz action on $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: I'm not sure "discrete" makes sense, but do you mean "proper"? And by bilipschitz, do you mean each map is bilipschitz, or do you mean uniformly bilipschitz? (the sup over group elements of the bilipschitz norm is finite)

Comment: In this case, by "discrete" I mean that orbits do not have accumulation points. I have also seen this called "accumulation-free". And you are correct, I did mean uniformly bilipschitz. I will change the question.

Comment: OK: for uniformly bilipschitz actions this "accumulation-free" assumption is equivalent to properness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Fix $k\ge 0$. Let $\Gamma$ be a discrete group. Then $\Gamma$ (a) has a proper cocompact, uniformly bilipschitz action on the Euclidean space $\mathbf{R}^k$ if and only if (b) it has an isometric one, if and only if (c) it has a finite index subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}^k$.

Proof: That (c) implies (b) is very standard and (b) trivially implies (a). Suppose (a): consider such an action $(g,x)\mapsto gx$, assume each map $(1/C,C)$-bilipschitz. Fix $x$ in $\mathbf{R}^k$ and a symmetric generating subset $S$ of $\Gamma$. Write $M=\max_{s\in S}d(x,sx)$ and $C'=CM$.

Then $g\mapsto gx$ is a quasi-isometry.  For $g,h\in\Gamma$, let $n=d_S(g,h)$ be their word distance: consider elements $g_0,\dots,g_n$ with $g_0=g$, $g_n=h$, $d(g_i,g_{i+1})\le 1$. Then

$$d(gx,hx)\le \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} d(g_ix,g_{i+1}x)\le C\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} d(x,g_i^{-1}g_{i+1}x)\le nCM=C'd_S(g,h),$$

and $d(gx,hx)\ge C^{-1}d(x,g^{-1}h)$ which tends to infinity when $d_S(g,h)$ tends to infinity.

So $x\mapsto gx$ Lipschitz, uniformly proper, and has cobounded image and is a map between geodesic spaces. Hence it is a quasi-isometry.

We conclude by using that a group that is quasi-isometric to $\mathbf{R}^k$ satisfies (c). (This is a standard consequence of Gromov's theorem on groups with polynomial growth, e.g. using Pansu's theorem, and also admits proofs not appealing to Gromov's theorem.)

Comment: Thank you for the nice and compact argument!